# Set Radiobuttonlist Selected from Codebehind

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Hey I have a radiobuttonlist and trying to set one of the radiobuttons to selected based on a session variable but proving impossible.

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist id="radio1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:listitem id="option1" runat="server" value="All"/>
   <asp:listitem id="option2" runat="server" value="1" />
   <asp:listitem id="option3" runat="server" value="2" />
</asp:radiobuttonlist>
```

I.e How can I set option2 to selected in code behind ?

Comment: listitem does not have the id property

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do:

```
radio1.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

But this is the most simple form and would most likely become problematic as your UI grows. Say, for instance, if a team member *inserts* an item in the `RadioButtonList` above `option2` but doesn't know we use *magic numbers* in code-behind to select - now the app selects the wrong index!

Maybe you want to look into using [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) in order to determine the `ListItem` actually required, by name, and selecting appropriately. For instance:

```
//omitting possible null reference checks...
var wantedOption = radio1.FindControl("option2").Selected = true;
```

Comment: I wonder how it is possible to do a FindControl on a ListItem as it lacks the ID property. Only properties I can recall are Selected, Enabled, Text and Value. Any ideas?

Comment: listitem does not have the id property therefore I would choose http://stackoverflow.com/a/11582680/1271898 (Marquito's answer)

Answer (score 20):

The best option, in my opinion, is to use the `Value` property for the `ListItem`, which is available in the `RadioButtonList`.

I must remark that [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does **NOT** have an ID property.

So, in your case, to select the second element (option2) that would be:

```
// SelectedValue expects a string
radio1.SelectedValue = "1";
```

Alternatively, yet in very much the same vein you may supply an int to SelectedIndex.

```
// SelectedIndex expects an int, and are identified in the same order as they are added to the List starting with 0.
radio1.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this option:

```
radio1.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
```

Comment: This solution worked for me while Marquito's didn't for some reason. The reason might be because I had set <asp:ListItem Selected="True" for the first item.

Answer (score 5):

We can change the item by value, here is the trick:

```
radio1.ClearSelection();
radio1.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;// 1 is the value of option2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rad_id = document.getElementById('<%=radio_btn_lst.ClientID %>');
var radio = rad_id.getElementsByTagName("input");
radio[0].checked = true;

//this for javascript in asp.net try this in .aspx page
```

// if you select other radiobutton  increase [0] to [1] or [2] like this

Comment: radio_btn_lst : your radiobuttonlist ID