# Radio Button List not properly selecting new value

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am having trouble getting a radio button from a Radio Button List to become selected in an IF statement. Everything else is working correctly when the IF is true, except for this. Request Pending is the default value, but I need to be able to have the "Waiting for Approval" Button selected when the IF is True.

My HTML code is:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbGiftStatus" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
    runat="server" TabIndex="3">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Request Pending" Selected="True" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Pending" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Completed" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Waiting for Approval" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

My C# is this:

```
rbGiftStatus.SelectedIndex = 4;
```

and I have tried other ways suchs as:

```
rbGiftStatus.Text = "4";
rbGiftStatus.SelectedItem = "4";
rbGiftStatus.SelectedValue = "4";
```

None of them seem to work, and I can't figure out why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SelectedIndex is the correct way: [Set Radiobuttonlist Selected from Codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662113/set-radiobuttonlist-selected-from-codebehind)

But, you are using SelectedIndex of 4, which is out of range of the array.  C# is 0-based indexing, so the first item is index 0.  That would make your 4th item index 3.

`rbGiftStatus.SelectedIndex = 3;` should do it.

Comment: While the code compiles, this still isn't changing the selection of the radiobuttonlist. I'm not sure what the problem is, as several lbltest.Visable = true; labels, textboxes and other controls are functioning correctly, the correct radio button in the RBL just isn't being selected (to clarify, no new radiobutton is being selected, the default is just staying selected)

Comment: Take out `Selected="true"` from your first item's ASPX markup.  That may be over-riding your setting.

Comment: Tried it, still no luck. I'm guessing there is something else in the code that may be affecting this. AJAX or Jquery, perhaps...Other than that, I have no idea... I do appreciate correcting my indexing though

Comment: That is odd.  Are you setting the SelectedIndex anywhere else, like `Page_Load` that isn't wrapped in an `if(!IsPostBack)` conditional?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
rbGiftStatus.SelectedIndex = 3; //index max is 3 for 4 elements
```

Answer (score 2):

The index starts with a 0 and not a 1.  So if you have 4 items in your RBL then the index range will be 0-3.  In this case you are calling an index of 4 which does not exists.

Try  `rbGiftStatus.SelectedIndex = 3;`