# Setting RadioButtonList selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to select the radiobuttonlist's using the following code but it never get selected.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdBond" CssClass="RadioButtonList"
                            runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and I tried both of the follwing methods but doesn't work.

```
       ListItem l2 = rdOffset.Items.FindByValue(cd.BondReq.ToString());
        if (l2 != null)
            l2.Selected = true;

        rdOffset.SelectedValue = cd.Offset.ToString();
```

Please help to fix it.

Comment: Just tested, `SelectValue` works fine. What's the value of `cd.Offset`  property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this change :

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdBond" CssClass="RadioButtonList"
                            runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected =True >Yes</asp:ListItem> <%--change this in your code--%>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdBond" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

// in code file
rdBond.SelectedValue = "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662113/set-radiobuttonlist-selected-from-codebehind), you should use `values` when dealing with list items.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdBond" CssClass="RadioButtonList" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                     <asp:ListItem value="yes"/>
                     <asp:ListItem value="no"/>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

ListItem A = rdOffset.Items.FindByValue("yes");
ListItem B = rdOffset.Items.FindByValue("no");

var a = A.Selected
var b = B.Selected
```