# Set radio button selected value according to the value retrieved from database result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbnPropertyType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Commercial"   Value="1" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="Residential" Value="2" />
```

This is ma aspx code.
and .cs code is

```
? = dtPolicyInfo.Rows[0]["PropertyType"].ToString();
```

How to  set radio button selected value based on database result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Radiobuttonlist Selected from Codebehind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662113/set-radiobuttonlist-selected-from-codebehind)

Comment: No it is not. because database value may be commercial or Residential. according to property type value it should be selected for edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, clear the selected list:

```
rbnPropertyType.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Now search items by value or text and then select it.

```
rbnPropertyType.Items.FindByValue(dtPolicyInfo.Rows[0]["PropertyType"].ToString()).Selected = true;
rbnPropertyType.Items.FindByText(dtPolicyInfo.Rows[0]["PropertyType"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string PropertyTypeID= dtPolicyInfo.Rows[0]["PropertyType"].ToString();
rbnPropertyType.Items.FindByText(PropertyTypeID).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one it may help:

```
rbnPropertyType.ClearSelection();
 rbnPropertyType.SelectedIndex = rbnPropertyType.Items.IndexOf(rbnPropertyType.Items.FindByValue(dtPolicyInfo.Rows[0]["PropertyType"].ToString()));
```