# asp RadioButton not selected when Checked="true"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I have two radio buttons "Yes" and "No" and I want the "No" radio button to be selected by default. However, I can't get it be be selected through the asp code or by the code behind. Am I doing this completely wrong or did I just miss something.

ASP code:

```
<div class="query_header" runat="server" id="ScanOnStartup">
    <div class="formlabel" style="width: 300px">Perform Scan on startup</div>
    <div class="formfield" style="line-height: 10px">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="scanOnStartupYes" Text="Yes" GroupName="ScanOnStartupRadio" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"  Checked="false"/>&nbsp
        <asp:RadioButton ID="sanOnStartupNo" Text="No" GroupName="ScanOnStartupRadio" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"  Checked="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="formdivider"></div>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {               
                this.scanOnStartupNo.Checked = true;

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Radiobuttonlist Selected from Codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662113/set-radiobuttonlist-selected-from-codebehind)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay aside from the typo "sanOnStartupNo", I know where the problem is coming from. There was actually another control from my code behind that renders the page and that is where the selection for the radio button is being set. I added in code for my radio button and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make a radio button checked by default on page load , you can do one of the above

From the front end , you can add the property

```
Checked="checked"
```

From the code behind, you can write it as

```
scanOnStartupNo.Checked=true
```

When I checked your code , You have made a spelling mistake in declaring the ID of NO button. That was why the code behind code piece was not working

Comment: Good catch on the typo! I've tried Checked="checked" before and that doesn't work for asp. But I've found out there were other codes in my code behind that actually controls the radio button and I fixed it from there. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. If you found the answer was correct, mark it as answer . Also if you liked the way it was answered, upvote